# Send VF pdf as attachment from console

Tags: apex, visualforce, email

```
PageReference pdf = 
    new PageReference('https://c.na35.visual.force.com/apex/ReimbursementVoucher');
Attachment attach = new Attachment();
Blob attachBody;

try {
    attachBody = pdf.getContent();
} catch (VisualforceException e) {
    attachBody = Blob.valueOf('Error attaching the right file.');
}
attach.Body = attachBody;
attach.Name = reimb.Employee_Name__r.name+'.pdf';
attach.contentType = 'pdf';

Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
efa.setFileName(attach.Name);
efa.setBody(attach.Body);
fileAttachments.add(efa);
mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
```

How to send a pdf attachment from visualforce page?

Comment: Is your current code experiencing any specific issue that you would care to share? Please **[edit]** your question to make it clear what is wrong with your current attempt.

Comment: I am not getting any attachment in email

Comment: In your code above, you are not setting the `blob` as the body of the `EmailFileAttachment`. I guess this is the problem.

Comment: Never hardcode URL, its really bad, use `PageReference pdf = new PageReference(Page.ReimbursementVoucher);` instead

Answer (score 0):

There is a Salesforce [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_sending_attachments.htm) detailing something very similar to your requirement.

There are few pieces you need to take care of, make sure your vf page has render as attribute as shown below

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="PDF">
```

and then you need to create EmailFileAttachment, something like

```
// Reference the attachment page, pass in the account ID
PageReference pdf = Page.attachmentPDF;
pdf.getParameters().put('id',(String)account.id);
pdf.setRedirect(true);

// Take the PDF content
Blob b = pdf.getContent();

// Create the email attachment
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
efa.setBody(b);
```

Also, check-out best practices for [redering PDF files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm) in apex.